# How to remove multiple attribute in tag helper ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tag-helpers

In my code behind:

```
var lstGroupProduct = await _db.GroupProduct.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.Name,
            Value = x.GroupProductId.ToString()
        }).ToListAsync();
```

And my code tag helper:

```
<select asp-for="ListGroupProduct" name="groupProductId" id="groupProductId" asp-items="@Model.ListGroupProduct">
</select>
```

But when code render to HTML will:

```
<select name="groupProductId" id="groupProductId" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Normal</option>
    <option value="2">Hard</option>
    <option value="3">Skin care, pill</option>
</select>
```

When code renders the HTML, I expectit NOT to include multiple attributes. I tried to remove by jQuery but seem this not best selection.

Comment: `asp-for="ListGroupProduct"` and what is this `ListGroupProduct`? That sounds like a collection property, so the `asp-for` tag helper has helpfully allowed multiple values. I suspect what you want is `<select asp-for="groupProductId" asp-items="@Model.ListGroupProduct">`

Comment: groupProductId not exist in my model. So, we should add groupProductId to model?

Comment: If you want to provide the `name=""` manually, then just drop the `asp-for=""` completely.

Comment: This working for me, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

`asp-for` attribute will result in the multiple attribute being rendered.

```
<select asp-for="ListGroupProduct" name="groupProductId" id="groupProductId" asp-items="@Model.ListGroupProduct">
</select>
```

This will render the HTML markup for the select element with the `multiple` attribute which will allow the user to select multiple options.

Use `name` attribute to bind: it will not generate `multiple` attribute .

```
<select name="ListGroupProduct" name="groupProductId" id="groupProductId" asp-items="@Model.ListGroupProduct">
</select>
```

Output:

```
<select name="groupProductId" id="groupProductId">
    <option value="1">Normal</option>
    <option value="2">Hard</option>
    <option value="3">Skin care, pill</option>
</select>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0